# +Android Webview - how to autoscroll a page?

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

I'd like to open a html-page in a webview and make it auto-scroll downwards automatically in accordance with an interval set through a timer.

Although below example is for desktop, this link should give you an idea what I want to achieve (enable autoscrolling in the upper right part of the page):

[example](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/b/bruce_springsteen/the_river_crd.htm)

First I thought about opening a webpage and then use some kind of code which would simulate/trigger DPAD-down (or Arrow-down). In Windows Mobile, I believe there was something called SendKeys but I couldn't find something similar in the Android-SDK (except for a test-SDK which I doubt I could use for publishing my app in AndroidMarket) so I guess the way mentioned above is not possible.

Another solution could perhaps be a java-script but the webpages are not created by me so I can't insert any anchor.

However, I noted that Webview has some methods called PageDown (and PageUp) which could also be a solution but I am afraid a PageDown would be too much for scrolling the way I want. I want the scrolling to be slow and smooth, more like a line at a time.

Do you have any ideas how I could implement this? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using,
`View.scrollBy(int x, int y)` to scroll the `WebView`.
**Use:**
 `computeVerticalScrollOffset(),`
`computeVerticalScrollExtent()` 
`computeVerticalScrollRange()`  to calculate a maximum y value.

Comment: I had a look at the android-documentation and the parameters are pixels. I must admit that I am not an expert at formulas. How would you implement it? Do you mind showing this in code?

Comment: Here's a code chunk to scroll down a line or so: 

// get these once, they probably won't change 

int scrollExtent = this.computeVerticalScrollExtent(); 

int scrollRange = this.computeVerticalScrollRange(); 

int dx = 12; // or calculate the line height here

// get this every time, it will change 

int scrollOffset = this.computeVerticalScrollOffset(); 

if (scrollOffset + dy > scrollRange - scrollExtent) {

    dy = (scrollRange - scrollExtent - scrollOffset);

}

webview.scrollBy(0,dy);