# Auto-scrolling a WebView with handlers

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

I want to autoscroll down a page loaded in a WebView from top to bottom, given a certain number of pixel per a certain number of ms.
I've seen this thread: [+Android Webview - how to autoscroll a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069765/android-webview-how-to-autoscroll-a-page) but On a lot of other thread they say using a Timer for this is a bad idea, so I used [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) for handlers: to create my handlers. right now my code looks like this:

```
private Handler mHandler=new Handler();

private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_url);
        webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        mHandler.postAtTime(this, 200);
    }
};
```

If I only call it once, (removing the last line that calls it again) it works, it goes down then stop. However if I try to make it scroll down gradually with this code, the view doesn't seem to get invalidated (or it's getting invalidated but not redrawn). With the debugger I can see that the mScrollY property of the WebView has increased, but the view doesn't move.

My guess is that system is waiting for all changes to the view to redraw it. Is there any way to make the view update at every iteration, or a better way to do this?

Note: I didn't place the end of page check and the stop button in there because they are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer;

```
private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_url);
        webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};
```

Using postDelayed instead of postAtTime fixed it.
While postAtTime(runnable,0) works to start the loop, postAtTime expect a time as the second parameter, since I passed only 200ms, it though it was late and immediately did the second(and the next) iteration, leaving no time for the element to be drawn.
postDelayed expect a number of ms to wait before executing again, which leaves the system the time to redraw the window and do other events.

Comment: How do you stop the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scroll.scrollTo(0, webview .getTop());//if want to go on top
scroll.scrollTo(0, webview .getBottom());//if want to go on top
```

Comment: I'm not sure you even read my question... it's a webview not a scrollview, and I want things to scrolldown by a different controllable amount, slowly, not immediately.