# Auto-Scroll WebView

Tags: android, webview, autoscroll

I have a WebView which displays an HTML file and I would like to add an option to be able to scroll down automatically when a button is clicked with a given speed. How should I approach on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the speed of button clicks by taking difference in unix timestamp between clicks and then you can impliment something like

```
private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_url);
        webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};
```

I got the answer from link given below. Check it for details.

[Auto-scrolling a WebView with handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641576/auto-scrolling-a-webview-with-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

You just need an HTML button which performs a JavaScript call.

Something like:

```
$('a[href=#bottom]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

Inspired by: [Slow down scroll to top event by jQuery animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/slow-down-scroll-to-top-event-by-jquery-animate)